# How to retry failed scenario in Behave using python

Tags: python-behave

Can someone please tell me how I can run a failed test again in Behave using Python?

I want to re-run the failed test case automatically if it fails.

Answer (score 14):

The behave library actually has a `RerunFormatter` which can help you rerun the failing scenarios of your previous test-run. It creates a text file of all your failing scenarios like:

```
# -- file:rerun.features
# RERUN: Failing scenarios during last test run.
features/auth.feature:10
features/auth.feature:42
features/notifications.feature:67
```

To use the `RerunFormatter` all you need to do is put it in your behave configuration file (**behave.ini**):

```
# -- file:behave.ini
[behave]
format   = rerun
outfiles = rerun_failing.features
```

To rerun the failing scenarios, use this command:

```
behave @rerun_failing.features
```

Comment: If you try to run that last command in Powershell, you'll get an error message because of the "@".  To fix, put quotes around the argument `behave "@rerun_failing.features"`

Answer (score 9):

I know that's a later answer but it could help others.

There is another approach that also could help, it's implementing it under the environment.py file, you could do the retry by a specific tag.

> Provides support functionality to retry scenarios a number of times
> before their failure is accepted. This functionality can be helpful
> when you use behave tests in an unreliable server/network
> infrastructure.

For example, I am running tag "@smoke_test" on CI, so I choose this tag to patch with retry condition.

First, on your environment.py import the following:

```
# -- file: environment.py
from behave.contrib.scenario_autoretry import patch_scenario_with_autoretry
```

Then add the method:

```
# -- file:environment.py
#
def before_feature(context, feature):
    for scenario in feature.scenarios:
        if "smoke_test" in scenario.effective_tags:
            patch_scenario_with_autoretry(scenario, max_attempts=3)
```

*max_attempts are by default set as 3. I just described there to make it explicit that you can actually set how many retries you want.

Answer (score 0):

Rerun failed cases
While executing the feature file using the “behave” command we need to pass below arguments.So that it will copy all the details whichever test cases are failed while execution.

Arguments such as “-f rerun -o fileName.feature” . Here we can define any name “fileName.feature” to copy failed test details.

```
-f : format
-o : output file

behave -f rerun -o failed_testcases.feature -f allure_behave.formatter:AllureFormatter -o Report\allure_result
```

The above command will copy failed cases into “failed_testcases.feature” file

Command to run failed cases feature file
We need to use the “@” symbol before the feature file name to execute the feature file which has failed cases.

This feature file will not have any steps like (Given ,When,Then,And ,But).So that we need to use @ symbol to execute.

```
behave @failed_testcases.feature
```