# How to automatically rerun failed scenarios in Behave using Python

Tags: automated-tests, python-behave

Is it possible for Behave to automatically rerun only failed scenarios and generate one report?

Example: given I have a test suite with 10 scenarios, after a run it I have 8 scenarios passed, and 2 scenarios failed.  At this point I would like Behave to rerun those two failed scenarios 2-3 times, and then generate one report. In case those failed scenarios pass after second or third rerun, I would like them to be marked as passed.

I've seen similar questions, but none of the suggested solutions seem to work for me. I'd appreciate any ideas :)

Comment: That's exactly what I answered on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62995134/13234986